# Symbolic logic constructing proof from premise to a conclusion

Tags: logic

I am studying symbolic logic and I want to clarify if my proof is correct or not.

Symbols :
~ : Negation

<=> : Bicondtiional

- : Conjunction

p > q : If p then q

Problem:

B                  premise

~C                 premise

\ ~(B <=> C)         conclusion

My proof:

1. B          prem
2. ~C         prem
3. B * ~C     Conjunction 1,2
4. ~(~B v C) DEMorgan 3
5. ~(B > C)  Conditional exchange 4
6. ~(B > C ) v ~(C > B) Addition 5
7. ~( (B > C ) * ( C > B ) ) DEMorgan 6
8. ~(B <=> C) Bi-conditional Exchange

So what I'm worried about is step 6.
Everytime I use addition, I feel like I'm doing wrongly

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid:

$\begin{array}{r l l}
1.&B &\text{prem}\\
2.& \lnot C &\text{prem}\\
3.& B \land\lnot C & \text{Conjunction 1,2}\\
4.&\lnot(\lnot B \lor C) & \text{DEMorgan 3}\\
5.&\lnot (B \to C) &\text{Conditional exchange 4}\\
6.&\lnot(B \to C ) \lor \lnot(C \to B) & \text{Addition 5}\\
7.&\lnot ( (B \to C ) \land ( C \to B ) ) & \text{DEMorgan 6}\\
8.&\lnot (B \leftrightarrow C)& \text{Bi-conditional Exchange}\end{array}$

> So what I'm worried about is step 6. Everytime I use addition, I feel like I'm doing wrongly

Nope, it is valid.  When something is derived, you may infer that that *or* something else is derivable too.

When $A$ holds, then $A\lor B$ does too.$${A\over A\lor B}{\text{(addition)}}$$

You are not claiming that $B$ is true when $A$ is; you are merely claiming that *at least one* of $A\text{ or } B$ must be true *when* $A$ is given to be true.

---

Addition derives a *weaker* statement from a stronger one.

Comment: Thank you, Graham! I appreciate